# CSS JS and Links not loading when deploy Spring boot as war in Tomcat

Tags: java, html, css, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot web application, it works fine when running as executable jar, but when I build as war and deploy to Tomcat, the css, js files are not loading and looking into further, I found out all links are pointing to root context path `"/"`, I tried changing `base href = "./"` this fixed the problem of loading css and js, but I need to do that in lot of pages. 
Also the links in `<a>` still points to root context path and to make this work I need prefix`'./'` . Below are my code snips,

**CSS and JS link**

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Tag**

```
<a class="topHeader" href="/activateAccount"></a>
```

Is there a shortcut to fix this problem or should I change `<base href> and <a href>` in all the pages? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: do u use thymeleaf?

Comment: No,I don’t use thymleaf

Comment: how u render html ? jsp?

Comment: Yes I am using jsp

Comment: What is your root context path?

Comment: My application url is http://localhost:8080/test and root is “/“ that is http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no short cut or quick fix for this, I removed "/" in links in all anchor tags and that worked for me.

Example

```
<a href="/resetPassword" style="float: right;">
```

changed to

```
<a href="resetPassword" style="float: right;">
```